# Query speed of a spark cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-ec2, tableau-api, hortonworks-data-platform

I have Hortonworkks Data Platform (HDP2.4) deployed on seven m4.2xlarge Red Hat instances on AWS EC2. The cluster has Spark and I am using Spark by connecting with Tableau for querying. I was asked about the query speed and I am not sure how to estimate the query speed. What factors should I consider or is there a direct way of knowing the query speed of a spark cluster?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am doing the same Analysis. The speed seems to be slow when rendering the tableau report. So to analyze the speed you need to look at the logs that connects Tableau to the Spark Cluster.

In our case it is Thrift Server 2 and the logs are located at: `/var/log/spark/spark-root-org.apache.spark.sql.hive.thriftserver.HiveThriftServer2-<<ip>>.out` you will have an ip address at the end of the log name.

When you look through the logs you will see `INFO SparkExecuteStatementOperation: Running query` and a query. There are way too many queries executed for a dashboard.

You can get a high-level idea on the same. If you want an in-depth analysis look at the Thrift Server stages in the **Resource Manager** from the EMR Cluster Details Page. When in the Resource Manager you will be able to see the containers that are being used for the Query as well.

Alternatively, you may take the queries and run the same on Spark and see how it performs.